# SQL exclude first ID entry

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need to exclude first id entry, and display the rest on my wordpress, I have never used sql before.

```
$all_users_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->users.ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY %s ASC", $sort ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Wordpress, but try this:

```
$all_users_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $wpdb->users.ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE $wpdb->users.ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN($wpdb->users.ID) FROM $wpdb->users) ORDER BY %s ASC", $sort ));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   ID > (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$all_users_id = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT `$wpdb->users.ID` FROM `$wpdb->users` WHERE `$wpdb->users.ID` != 1 ORDER BY %s ASC", $sort ));
```

The query used:

```
SELECT `$wpdb->users.ID`
FROM `$wpdb->users`
WHERE `$wpdb->users.ID` != 1
ORDER BY %s ASC
```

Fast and simple... Without sub-querys! :)

Comment: This will only exclude ID #1,  which is not necessarily the 'first' ID

Answer (score 0):

If it's a mysql db then use the limit clause:

```
SELECT `$wpdb->users.ID`
FROM `$wpdb->users`
ORDER by $sort ASC
LIMIT 1,9999999
```

C.